# Wrong filling order when loading ListView elements with Loader

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using a Loader in a ListView delegate to increase the performance when loading expensive delegate models.

My code looks like this:

```
delegate: Component {
        Loader {
            asynchronous: true
            sourceComponent: MyDelegateComponent {}
        }
    }
```

The model comes from C++ (QAbstractListModel implementation).

The problem is that the filling order of the list is wrong. It comes from bottom to top, creating a strange view for the user, who needs to wait to see the first list element.

Is it possible to change this filling order to load top element first? The model in the C++ data is well ordered.

Comment: remove  `Component`

Comment: I have the same behavior with or without Component. Is there any difference when using directly Loader as a delegate?

Comment: please provide [mcve], it is very difficult to solve a problem without seeing it